# How to filter certain words into a new column with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a `Status` column like below:

```
      Status
      ------------------------
4     probable for Thursday
7     plans to play on Tuesday
8     questionable Tuesday
13    won't play on Sunday
15    will start on Saturday
16    is questionable
17    will not play Thursday
32    questionable Monday
35    good to go vs. CLE
36    probable vs. Cavaliers
37    questionable Monday
40    will not play Saturday
41    drops 35/16/7 on Mavs
42    will play vs. DAL
43    probable vs. Mavericks
45    will play vs. Knicks
47    'hopeful' to play Tues
52    will play on Sunday
55    will play on Saturday
56    headed toward a GTD?
```

I want to make a new column called `Game_Status`. The `Game_Status` would filter through the `Status` column like below:

```
      Status                      Game_Status
      ------------------------    ------------
4     probable for Thursday       probable
7     plans to play on Tuesday    plans to play
8     questionable Tuesday        questionable
13    won't play on Sunday        won't play
15    will start on Saturday      will start
16    is questionable             questionable
17    will not play Thursday      will not play
32    questionable Monday         questionable
35    good to go vs. CLE          good to go
36    probable vs. Cavaliers      probable
37    questionable Monday         questionable
40    will not play Saturday      will not play
41    drops 35/16/7 on Mavs       
42    will play vs. DAL           will play
43    probable vs. Mavericks      probable
45    will play vs. Knicks        will play
47    'hopeful' to play Tues      hopeful
52    will play on Sunday         will play
55    will play on Saturday       will play
56    headed toward a GTD?        GTD
```

On line 41, `Game_Status` would be left blank since none of the words/phrases are found. The filter would go through these words/phrases:

```
gamestatuswords = ['out', 'questionable', 'doubtful','locker room','won\'t return','won\'t play','fractured','sprained','hyperextended','bruised',
                    'probable to return', 'uncertain', 'game-time decision','miss','weeks', 'GTD','suspended','suspension','day-to-day',
                    'game time decision', 'broken', 'torn', 'separated', 'ACL','unlikely to play','will not play','without timetable','retire',
                    'ejected','ejection','probable','hopeful','will play', 'available to play','will start','plans to play','good to go','cleared']
```

**How do I implement the `gamestatuswords` to get the `Game_Status` column from filtering through the `Status` column?**

I have tried this out:

```
df['Game_Status'] = np.where(df['Status'].eq('gamestatuswords'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use, [`Series.str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) along with the regex pattern:

```
pattern = '|'.join(gamestatuswords)
df['Game_Status'] = df['Status'].str.findall(pattern).str.join(', ')
```

---

```
# print(df)
                      Status    Game_Status
4      probable for Thursday       probable
7   plans to play on Tuesday  plans to play
8       questionable Tuesday   questionable
13      won't play on Sunday     won't play
15    will start on Saturday     will start
16           is questionable   questionable
17    will not play Thursday  will not play
32       questionable Monday   questionable
35        good to go vs. CLE     good to go
36    probable vs. Cavaliers       probable
37       questionable Monday   questionable
40    will not play Saturday  will not play
41     drops 35/16/7 on Mavs               
42         will play vs. DAL      will play
43    probable vs. Mavericks       probable
45      will play vs. Knicks      will play
47    'hopeful' to play Tues        hopeful
52       will play on Sunday      will play
55     will play on Saturday      will play
56      headed toward a GTD?            GTD
```

Comment: How to I load `Series.str.findall`?

Comment: You dont have to load it its just the property on the pandas series.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex pattern:

```
df['Game-status'] = (df.Status
                       .str.extract(fr'\b({"|".join(gamestatuswords)})\b')[0]
                       .fillna('')
                    )
```

Output:

```
                      Status    Game-status
4      probable for Thursday       probable
7   plans to play on Tuesday  plans to play
8       questionable Tuesday   questionable
13      won't play on Sunday     won't play
15    will start on Saturday     will start
16           is questionable   questionable
17    will not play Thursday  will not play
32       questionable Monday   questionable
35        good to go vs. CLE     good to go
36    probable vs. Cavaliers       probable
37       questionable Monday   questionable
40    will not play Saturday  will not play
41     drops 35/16/7 on Mavs               
42         will play vs. DAL      will play
43    probable vs. Mavericks       probable
45      will play vs. Knicks      will play
47    'hopeful' to play Tues        hopeful
52       will play on Sunday      will play
55     will play on Saturday      will play
56      headed toward a GTD?            GTD
```